# Flush jqModal popup content on popup close

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

I'm using jqModal pop up windows, two different pop ups are used which are triggered from different sections of code. Both pop ups are triggered smoothly but when i close a pop-up and open another, overlay window populates contents of both pop ups. I'm using jqmHide() to close the popup. Is there a way to flush the pop up content when i close it?

```
$('a.jqModal').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $( $(this).attr('href') )
            .jqm({ modal:true, overlay:80, toTop: true })
            .jqmShow();

        return false;
    });

    $(".jqm").click(function () {
        $("#Dv_AddProfile").jqmHide();
        $("#Dv_DuplicateProfile").jqmHide();
    });
```

Html:

```
<div id="Dv_AddProfile" class="jqmWindow">
   <span id="Spn_Close" class="jqm"><button>Close</button></span>
   //...
   //popup content

</div>
<div id="Dv_DuplicateProfile" class="jqmWindow">
   <span id="Spn_Close" class="jqm"><button>Close</button></span>
   //...
   /// popup content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code looks a bit strange. Initialize your modals once via;

```
$('div.jqmWindow').jqm({
  modal:true, 
  overlay:80, 
  toTop: true, 
  trigger: False
});
```

I set trigger to false, because I noticed that you're manually triggering the modals. The default looks for anchor elements with a class of "jqModal".

You didn't include the anchor elements in your HTML example, but I assume they look like:

```
<a href="#Dv_AddProfile" class="jqModal">Open AddProfile Modal</a>
<a href="#Dv_DuplicateProfile" class="jqModal">Open DuplicateProfile Modal</a>
```

Then, you can trigger the modals similarly without the need for event.stopProgogation() ; e.g.

```
$('a.jqModal').click(function(){
  $( $(this).attr('href') ).jqmShow();
    return false;
});
```

Now, lets take advantage of the default closeClass behavior. This way you don't need the $(".jqm").click() function to close your modals.

Change the jqm class of the closing span elements to "jqmClose", e.g.

```
<div id="Dv_DuplicateProfile" class="jqmWindow">
  <span id="Spn_Close" class="jqmClose"><button>Close</button></span>
  //...
  /// popup content
</div>
```

NOTE: you may need to move the jqmClose class to the button element for the click event to fire; e.g.

```
<span id="Spn_Close"><button class="jqmClose">Close</button></span>
```

FINALLY; if you want to clear the content of a modal on hide, do so via a custom onHide callback. I run into this problem often (e.g. to stop a video playing w/o having to worry about a javascript api into the plugin).

Something like

```
onHide: function(hash){
  // hide modal
  hash.w.hide();

  // clear content
  $('div.cleared-on-close',hash.w).empty();

  // remove overlay
  hash.o.remove();
}
```

So here's your modified example;

Markup

```
<a href="#Dv_AddProfile" class="jqModal">Open AddProfile Modal</a>
<a href="#Dv_DuplicateProfile" class="jqModal">Open DuplicateProfile Modal</a>

<div id="Dv_AddProfile" class="jqmWindow">
   <span id="Spn_Close"><button class="jqmClose">Close</button></span>
   <div class="cleared-on-close">...</div>
   ...
</div>
<div id="Dv_DuplicateProfile" class="jqmWindow">
   <span id="Spn_Close"><button class="jqmClose">Close</button></span>
   <div class="cleared-on-close">...</div>
   ...
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('div.jqmWindow').jqm({
  modal:true, 
  overlay:80, 
  toTop: true, 
  trigger: False,
  onHide: function(hash){
    // hide modal
    hash.w.hide();

    // clear content
    $('div.cleared-on-close',hash.w).empty();

    // remove overlay
    hash.o.remove();
  }
});

$('a.jqModal').click(function(){
  $( $(this).attr('href') ).jqmShow();
  return false;
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: very well scripted briceburg. default initialization works well if we have one pop up but i have more than one in this case. I used jqmClose with span and it didn't work for me but now it works with a button. :) Thank you very much for your support.